# Cascade deletion on paranoid tables - Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a relationship between two paranoid tables (User and Email) and I have the onDelete: 'cascade' option on the relationship ( Email.belongsTo(User, onDelete:'cascade') ).

The problem is that when I delete the user his email is **not** being deleted by cascade.

Did I make a mistake or there is bug on sequelize?

I am using **sequelize 2.0.0-rc2** on a **postgres** database.

Thanks.

PS.: Please take a look at the code I used for test:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
    , sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'test', 'test', {dialect: 'postgres'});

var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: Sequelize.STRING,
    birthday: Sequelize.DATE
}, {paranoid: true}); //Without paranoid the code works fine

var Email = sequelize.define('Email', {
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    primary: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
}, {paranoid: true}); //Without paranoid the code works fine

Email.belongsTo(User, {onDelete: 'cascade'});

sequelize.sync().success(function () {
    var userCreatedInstance = null;

    var deletedUserId = null;
    var cascadeDeletedEmailId = null;

    User
        .create({
            username: 'user1',
            birthday: new Date(1986, 06, 28)
        })
        .then(function (_user) {
            userCreatedInstance = _user;
            deletedUserId = userCreatedInstance.id;
            return Email.create({email: 'email1@test.com', primary: true, UserId: userCreatedInstance.id});
        })
        .then(function (createdEmail) {
            cascadeDeletedEmailId = createdEmail.id;
            return userCreatedInstance.destroy();
        })
        .then(function () {
            return User.find(deletedUserId);
        })
        .then(function (foundUser) {
            if(foundUser){
                throw new Error("Shouldn't find the user with this id");
            }
            return Email.find(cascadeDeletedEmailId);
        })
        .then(function (foundEmail){
            if(foundEmail){
                console.log(foundEmail.values);
                throw new Error("Shouldn't find the email with this id");
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want the cascade to work on paranoid, you will have to use hooks.
please find how i worked it around below

i added a afterDestroy hook on the parent table(base of the relatioship),
i made it get the model asssociated with with and called the destroy method on it. 
Easy as that!
I believe we could make it work this way till the maintainers give us another means

```html
// User Model
const User = sequelize.define('users', {....},
{
        tableName: 'users',
        deletedAt: 'deletedAt',
        paranoid: true,
        timestamps: true,
        hooks: {
            afterDestroy: function (instance, options) {
                instance.getProduct().then(product=> product.destroy()); // Softdelete on product table
                console.log('after destroy: destroyed');
            }
        }
    }
);

// Product Model
const Product = sequelize.define('products', {....},
{
        tableName: 'products',
        deletedAt: 'deletedAt',
        paranoid: true,
        timestamps: true,
    }
)

// User relationship with product
User.hasOne(Product,
    {
        as: 'Product',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        hooks: true,
        foreignKey: "userID"
    })
Product.belongsTo(User, {
    as: 'User',
    foreignKey: "userID"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the cascade option only sets up the database cascade option. There is no cascade deletion being done by sequelize.

But the sequelize team is going to work on cascade for paranoid table in the future.

There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2586